# convert table data into pdf , csv and excel in angular 2

Tags: angular, pdf-generation

I am using angular 2 and want to know how to print table and convert it into pdf,excel,csv.Is there any third party plugin in angular 2 which I use it.

Comment: Have you got the solution? If you got the solution, Then post your solution for your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer for your question. I only found a npm package to convert data into CSV:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv

I will update my answer if I find something more useful.

UPDATE:

I found out that the input data that you want to export has to be a JSON.